# My commits are shown as parallel ones whereas they should be sequential ones

Tags: git

I don't know what I did, but I'm right here in my Git repo:

[image]

When I look at the code, I can see that the `bdc2ea` commit is right after the `bdede5` one but I don't know how to make them be on the same line. It will prevent me from further squashing.

From IntelliJ or GitKraken, rebasing is not an option. What should I do to resolve this situation?

Comment: When you say "rebasing is not an option", maybe you just mean your organization has a policy against rebasing published branches. But when you have commits that are still only on your machine and you want to fetch remote changes, rebasing is *the* way to get those changes but make your history linear anyway.

Comment: Thanx @joanis. It's not an option because I've pushed this commit to remote. Now it's on remote, how can I change that is my question

Comment: You can't *change* it, but you can *rebase* it. Rebasing a commit (or series of commits) means *make new and improved commits*. You then switch from using the old (and lousy?) to the new (and supposedly improved)—and force everyone else, in every other clone of the repository, to switch as well. As long as that's just you on your laptop and GitHub/Bitbucket/GitLab/whatever-it-is (two repositories), that's not very challenging. If it's 500 clones scattered all across the world, it's harder.

Answer (score 2):

That has not to do with you, it is how git works.

> I don't know what I did, but I'm right here in my Git repo:

If you notice the last commit in Picture is there probably because you worked on same repo from different machines, or a colleague of you pushed changes while you committed without pulling the those latest changes first.

At some point, you (or IntelliJ, or Kraken, without you knowing it) did a pull and merged those changes in your local repo creating such a commit telling you that you merged a remote branch. That's my guess on why it did happened in first place.

That's how a decentralised VCS should work. If you don't want that, look how to rebase or squash your history so it will look linear.

I suggest you this: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History, and in general I would suggest you to read the whole book as if it were a Novel, you can get a lot out of it.

Answer (score 0):

##### The cause: git pull

So, I expect the way you created the merge commit `fc959b` in the first place is that you ran a simple `git pull` with the default configuration. At that point, `bcd2ea` was probably only on your local machine, while `bdede5` was already on the remote. Now, `git pull` is just a short-cut for `git fetch` followed by default by `git merge` (or `git rebase` if you change your configuration).

I don't like `git pull`, and almost never use it.

##### What you could have done to avoid it

To get that remote change on your machine without creating a merge, and thus keeping a linear history, there are a number of things you could have done.

- `git pull --rebase` fetches the remote changes and rebases any local commits onto them
- `git fetch`, then inspect the repo, notice there is a divergence and get rid of it by running `git rebase` (which is exactly the same operation `git pull --rebase` does, except you get to see what's going to happen before it happens)

My general advice is to avoid using `git pull` in the first place. It's what you find in every tutorial and every manual, yet so often it defaults to doing not what you want. `git fetch` is your friend: it brings in the remote changes locally, which you can inspect, and then *you* can decide, oh yeah, I want to merge/rebase/whatever.

You can change your configuration to make a rebase the default second operation that a pull does, like this:

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
```

but I'm not a fan of that solution either. I want to see what's going to happen, so I always fetch instead.

##### How to fix a pull (before pushing)

If you didn't (or hadn't) pushed the merge commit `fc959b` to the remote yet, the local merge was completely undoable and no one would notice.

At the time you did the `git pull`, you were on `bdc2ea`, so you can go back there and "try again", sort of. Assuming you have no local changes (`git stash` them if you do), you can use a hard reset:

```
git reset --hard bdc2ea
```

Now if you want to be sure nobody else pushes stuff on remote in the mean time, do `git fetch` again, and do the rebase:

```
git rebase origin/pipeline_hooks
```

(I took the branch name from your logs, but `git rebase` would have probably worked too since that's likely your remote-tracking branch.)

Now you've got a linear history you can push.

##### But I already pushed the merge, what do I do now?

Well, now we're falling into the realm of opinion, but you have two perfectly fine choices you can make here:

1. Accept that once a while, a pointless bubble will happen in the history and it's really not that bad (if you work with a team, someone's going to do a careless pull no matter how many times you ask them not to, by personal experience, so I've decided to just live with these bubbles).
2. If you really can't live with it, follow @torek's advice: tell everyone you're going to fix the history, fix it, do a forced push, and tell everyone to reset their work from the fixed branch. And hope everyone was paying attention, because if someone does a careless pull, you might end up with a three way bubble and duplicated commits that you'll really want to fix and force push yet again.